# Calculating the Cumulative Mean in Python

Tags: python-3.x

i am new on programming and python. I made a simulation mm1 queue. I ran it properly. I took the results. I have an 5000 output. But now i should calculate the cumulative mean of average delays for every 100 period(1 to 100, 1 to 200... until 1 to 5000).

```
#data 4 (delay time) set assign to list of numpy array
npdelaytime = np.array(data[4][0:5000])  
#reshape the list of delay time 100 customer in each sample
npdelayreshape100 = np.reshape(npdelaytime, (-1,100))     
#mean of this reshape matrix
meandelayreshape100 = np.mean(npdelayreshape100, axis=1)  
cumsummdr100 = np.cumsum(meandelayreshape100)
a = range(1,51)     
meancsmdr100 = cumsummdr100 / a
```

I can figure this out like this. First reshape the 5000 sample point into to 100*50. Then taking the means of these matrix. Lastly cumsum of these means.

**My Question :** Is there a easy way to do this ?

Comment: Please share some code you have written and the specific problem you find

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What about replacing `range` by `np.arange` ?

Try:

```
meancsmdr100 = cumsummdr100 / np.arange(1,51)
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. I changed that line with yours. I made so much and simple calculations to get these results.  But i wanna learn that, is there a more professional way to get the results?

Comment: What do you mean by professional? There is no `cummean` function shipped in `numpy` but by using two builtins `cumsum` and `arange` the code is fairly clean, readable and reliable.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cum_mean(arr):
    cum_sum = np.cumsum(arr, axis=0)    
    for i in range(cum_sum.shape[0]):       
        if i == 0:
            continue        
        print(cum_sum[i] / (i + 1))
        cum_sum[i] =  cum_sum[i] / (i + 1)
    return cum_sum
```