# Calculate the running mean of the sequence passed in, returns a sequence of same length with the averages

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, append, average

How do I solve this?
If the input is `[1, 2, 3]` the output should be `[1, 1.5, 2]`. The `1` in the output is the average of the first element from the input. `1.5` from the output is the average of `1, 2`. `2` from the output is the average of `1, 2, 3`.

I tried to write this:

```
def running_mean(sequence):
    return sum(sequence)/len(sequence)
```

But then I only recieve the total average, 2.

Tried with for loop and append. But not sure how to write it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the Cumulative Mean in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005146/calculating-the-cumulative-mean-in-python)

Comment: This question might be useful: [Cumulative average in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70116095)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 - create partial arrays from initial elements of the array up to given index - in this case:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Step 2 - calculate average of each such partial array with `sum(x)/len(x)`

```
inp = [1, 2, 3]

def running_mean(inp):
    return [sum(x)/len(x) for x in (inp[:i+1] for i in range(0, len(inp)))]

print(running_mean(inp)) # [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
```

Comment: The required output is [1, 1.5, 2]

Comment: It does produce the required output - `1 == 1.0`

Comment: 1 is equivalent to 1.0 in a mathematical sense but they are different object types and OP clearly indicates that the result should contain integer values wherever possible

Answer (score 1):

I would use the built in function [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) which will give me the partial sum of the list.
Then just divide by the number of elements in the sum and you will get the average.

```
from itertools import accumulate

a = [1, 2, 3]

a_mean = [partial_sum / partial_len
          for partial_len, partial_sum in enumerate(accumulate(a), start=1)]
```

We use `start=1` at calling `enumerate` because we don't want to get the index in the iteration, but the amount of elements `accumulate` is adding up.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple you can use this :

```
res = []
j=0
for i in range(len(test)):
    i=0
    for x in range(j+1):
        i+=test[x]
    j+=1
    res.append(i/j)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the output exactly as indicated in your question you could do this:

```
def running_mean(sequence):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, len(sequence)+1):
        if (v := sum(sequence[:i])/i).is_integer():
            result.append(int(v))
        else:
            result.append(v)
    return result

print(running_mean([1,2,3]))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1.5, 2]
```

If you're happy with float values in the resulting list then it's simply:

```
def running_mean(sequence):
    return [sum(sequence[:i])/i for i in range(1, len(sequence)+1)]
```

... which would produce [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]